# How can I extract images from AZW?

Tags: azw

Is there any way to extract images from AZW? Is there any difference between the procedure for azw and azw3?

Answer (score 3):

Thanks Terence for your answer. It encouraged me to give it a go!

I did this by right clicking my book in the Calibre interface and then selecting 'Edit Book'.

I then used the 'File browser' (left hand panel) and scrolled down to the 'Images' section.

Next, I right clicked on Images and selected 'Select all Image files'

Finally, I right clicked on the image files below 'Images' and selected 'Export all XX selected files'.

For me this prompted me to save the files and put them all in a folder called 'images'.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way that I know is to use Calibre - https://calibre-ebook.com/

The eBook editor will allow you to select all the images embedded in the book and then extract them to your filesystem.